# How can I reference a non-global function with window[functionName]?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making something like a framework for JS. I want the users to be able to add functions to a specific action, just like in wordpress plugins:

```
add_action("wp_head", "functionName");
```

I looked at other questions, and the most appreciated answer was

```
window['functionName']
```

But how do I do it when the function "functionName" is **not global**, but sits within $(document).ready({}); for example? It throws an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined

There is one more option, that is to pass the user's function as an argument to add_action (if we suppose that my function will be named add_action as well):

```
add_action("some_event", functionName);
// in the framework's JS file:
function add_action(event, fn) {
    fn();
}
```

But I have a hunch that this will be inefficient as hell and a wrong way to do it.

Comment: adding a set of functions to execute when some other function triggers an action is called "event handling".

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted...

Comment: Are you saying you will have a set of pre-defined functions that the user can choose from, or that the user can somehow define their own functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last way — passing in the function — is actually the best way to do it. It is neither inefficient nor wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can put these functions on your own object and use it inside the document.ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var fns = {};
    fns.myFunc = function() {};

    // execute the function by name
    var fnName = "myFunc";
    fns[fnName]();
});
```

Or, if you want to reference it outside of the document.ready() scope, you can put it on the window object and make it your own namespaced global:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.myFunctionTable = {};
    window.myFunctionTable.myFunc = function() {};
});

// execute the function by name
var fnName = "myFunc";
window.myFunctionTable[fnName]();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  However, if you absolutely must have a global function, you can tack it onto the jQuery object:

```
$.yourSpecialFunction = function() {
  // ...
};
```

Worse, you could add it to `window`:

```
window.yourSpecialFunction = function() {
  // ...
}
```

But there's really no reason to do that.

Comment: So the solution here is to pass the function as an argument?

Comment: uhh ... what? An argument to what?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you really want to namespace your app -- so you have something like

`window.MY_APP = {...};`

or whatever, and then you add all your methods/properties/modules for the whole framework to that namespace.